# How can pass a token from k3s server to k3s agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, terraform, devops, k3s

I have two machines k3s-agent and k3s-server
the agent accept all the traffic that comes from the server

I can only pass the agent only through the server using ssh

but I need the server token to be passed through different servers(EC2 instances).

I stored the token in service

How can I pass a token from k3s server to k3s agent through packer/cloud-init?

Comment: Packer can retrieve a value from AWS Secrets or Key store: https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/hcl_templates/functions/contextual/aws_secretsmanager. Personally, i just force the key when I create the server with: `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | K3S_TOKEN=wibble INSTALL_K3S_CHANNEL=latest INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="server --disable=traefik" for the installation
        sh -`